# How to invert options value between two input select?

Tags: javascript, html, select, input

I have two input selects, with same options. I need to invert the options values between that two selects when I click in a trigger. For example:

```
<select id="source_currency">
 <option value="BRL" selected>BRL</option>
 <option value="USD">USD</option>
 <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>

<select id="target_currency">
 <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
 <option value="USD">USD</option>
 <option value="EUR" selected>EUR</option>
</select>
```

What I need is that with a click on a trigger happen this:

```
<select id="source_currency">
 <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
 <option value="USD">USD</option>
 <option value="EUR" selected>EUR</option>
</select>

<select id="target_currency">
 <option value="BRL" selected>BRL</option>
 <option value="USD">USD</option>
 <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>
```

I thought change the values with a function like this (but isn't work):

```
<a href="#" class="is-txt-green-light" id="invertConvert">Invert</a>

// JS
function invertCurrency() {
  let sourceCurrency = $('#source_currency');
  let targetCurrency = $('#target_currency');
  const triggerInvert = $('#invertConvert');

  triggerInvert.click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    sourceCurrency.val(targetCurrency.val())
  })
}
```

How can I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: You're just setting the target to the source.

Comment: Can I assume that both `select`s have only one option?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan No, they have more than one options. I'm editing my question.

Comment: where is element which id is `invertConvert`?

Comment: The `click` event is being captured inside a function? Is that function being called?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is update your code to temporarily store the `sourceCurrency` value before changing it and then also change the `targetCurrency` value

```js
function invertCurrency() {
  let sourceCurrency = $('#source_currency');
  let targetCurrency = $('#target_currency');
  const triggerInvert = $('#invertConvert');

  triggerInvert.click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const sourceVal = sourceCurrency.val();
    sourceCurrency.val(targetCurrency.val());
    targetCurrency.val(sourceVal);
  })
}

invertCurrency()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="source_currency">
 <option value="BRL" selected>BRL</option>
 <option value="USD">USD</option>
 <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>

<select id="target_currency">
 <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
 <option value="USD">USD</option>
 <option value="EUR" selected>EUR</option>
</select>

<button id='invertConvert'>Invert</button>
```

Comment: You do realize that `sourceVal` is subject to change, and therefore shouldn't be defined using `const`?

Comment: No, `sourceVal`  doesn't change

Comment: Updated with snippet

Comment: This is not working :/ If I put the vars in a `console.log` that returns the values, but don't invert :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to swap the values of the field like this:

When the user clicks the Invert button, the values of the fields are swapped.

```js
const triggerInvert = $('#invertConvert');

triggerInvert.click((e) => {
  let sourceCurrency = $('#source_currency');
  let sourceCurrency_val = sourceCurrency.val();

  let targetCurrency = $('#target_currency');
  let targetCurrency_val = targetCurrency.val();

  e.preventDefault();
  sourceCurrency.val(targetCurrency_val);
  targetCurrency.val(sourceCurrency_val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="source_currency">
  <option value="GBP" selected>Pound Sterling</option>
  <option value="USD">Dollar</option>
  <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
</select>

<select id="target_currency">
  <option value="GBP">Pound Sterling</option>
  <option value="USD">Dollar</option>
  <option value="EUR" selected>Euro</option>
</select>

<button id="invertConvert">
Convert
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a variable that holds one value before you replace it.

```js
let sourceCurrency = $('#source_currency > option');
let targetCurrency = $('#target_currency > option');
const triggerInvert = $('#invertConvert');

triggerInvert.on("click", function(){
  let option1 = sourceCurrency.val(); // Store first option
  sourceCurrency.val(targetCurrency.val()); // Copy second to first
  targetCurrency.val(option1); // Copy first to second
  
  // Report results
  console.log(sourceCurrency.val(), targetCurrency.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="source_currency"><option value="option_goo">Option Goo</option></select>

<select id="target_currency"><option value="option_foo">Option Foo</option></select>
<button id="invertConvert">Invert</button>
```

Comment: @Amessihel Did you run my snippet? Click the button and you'll see the values are swapped. Then click the button again and you'll see them swapped back.

Comment: @Amessihel The OP has changed the question since the original post. Originally, he asked for a swap of the `value`, not the displayed text. And, in the original, each `select` only had one item in it.  This answer does exactly what the original question asked for.

Comment: @Amessihel Thanks, but not worried about the down votes. I can afford it. ;)